# How to assign probabilities to dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, probability

I am trying to assign probabilities to dictionary keys. The dictionary is as follows.

```
my_dict = {0: 21, 1: 36, 2: 13, 3: 344, 4: 171, 5: 10, 6: 7, 7: 24, 8: 15, 9: 14, 10: 77, 11: 7, 12: 434, 13: 6, 14: 38, 15: 328, 16: 149, 17: 12, 18: 67, 19: 85, 20: 33, 21: 19, 22: 13, 23: 477, 24: 9, 25: 206, 26: 226, 27: 48, 28: 135, 29: 42, 30: 273, 31: 11, 32: 61, 33: 11, 34: 378, 35: 32, 36: 10, 37: 237, 38: 248, 39: 64, 40: 7, 41: 74, 42: 17, 43: 30, 44: 12, 45: 44, 46: 197, 47: 314, 48: 118, 49: 40, 50: 89, 51: 6, 52: 260, 53: 18, 54: 5, 55: 5, 56: 5, 57: 455, 58: 25, 59: 23, 60: 70, 61: 179, 62: 98, 63: 9, 64: 163, 65: 102, 66: 8, 67: 188, 68: 5, 69: 500, 70: 8, 71: 142, 72: 216, 73: 6, 74: 299, 75: 286, 76: 56, 77: 156, 78: 123, 79: 58, 80: 27, 81: 20, 82: 93, 83: 29, 84: 361, 85: 26, 86: 15, 87: 396, 88: 112, 89: 415, 90: 46, 91: 53, 92: 16, 93: 6, 94: 81, 95: 22, 96: 129, 97: 51, 98: 35, 99: 107}
```

The structure of the dictionary is - **key** denotes the label, and **values** denote the number of occurrences. How should I assign probabilities to the keys in the order of lowest occurrence having the highest probability and highest occurrence having the lowest probability?

My code:

```
sorted_dict = {key: value for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}

# Step 2: Calculate the probability of each key based on the sorted order
total_count = sum(sorted_dict.values())
probabilities = {key: (len(sorted_dict) - index)/total_count for index, (key, value) in enumerate(sorted_dict.items())}

# Print the probabilities

 for key, probability in probabilities.items():
     print(f"Key: {key}, Probability: {probability}")
    
print(sum(probabilities.values()))
```

The issue is, the probabilities do not add up to 1. It is not even close - I obtain the sum of probabilities ~ 0.45

Comment: Why are you subtracting `index`?

Comment: If I don't subtract index, I would get the same probability for all values in the dictionary.

Comment: Why are you using `len(sorted_dict)`? Obviously that the same for each element. Use `value`.

Comment: `key: value/total_count`

Comment: @Barmar, I wish to assign the highest probability to the lowest value. If I change that to key: value/total_count I get the lowest value with the lowest probability.

Comment: Then invert it: `1 - value/total_count`. Someone wrote that as an answer, but deleted it for some reason.

Comment: I am unsure if it helps, as the total probability of all values in the dictionary should add up to 1.

Comment: Indeed, the sum of those "probabilities" is `len(my_dict.values())`, not 1. (It's my deleted answer that proposed that.)

Comment: There are infinitely many probability distributions that will give more probability to smaller values in your initial dictionary than to larger values. If you have a specific distribution you need based on some kind of logic, you need to spell it out for us, we can't just randomly guess which you want. Your code is weighting by rank, so that the largest value in the dictionary corresponds to weight 1, and the smallest corresponds to weight `len(dictionary)`. It's not clear if that's really what you want (it's an unusual pick, as it completely ignores the specific values, except to sort).

Answer (score 0):

Let `total = sum(my_dict.values())`. The probability of each key `k` occurring is `v/total`, where `v == my_dict[k]`.

To make the more probable occurrences less probable, you can subtract each probability from 1, leaving you with a valid probability, but now your distribution isn't valid, since the sum of your new probabilities is not 1, but

```
n = len(my_dict.values())

sum(1 - v/total for v in my_dict.values())
  == n - sum(v/total for v in my_dict.values())
  == n - 1
```

So, if you divide `1 - v/total` by `n - 1`, your new probabilities sum to 1 and they remain between 0 and 1.

```
total = len(my_dict.values())
probabilities = {k: (1 - v/total)/(n - 1) for v in my_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `probabilities = {key: (len(sorted_dict) - index)/total_count for index, (key, value) in enumerate(sorted_dict.items())}`

to

`probabilities = {key: value/total_count for key, value in sorted_dict.items()}`

Comment: This is incorrect for the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Create inversely proportional weighted probabilities then normalize:

```py
total_count = sum(my_dict.values())
probabilities = {key: 1 - val/total_count for key, val in my_dict.items()}

prob_sum = sum(probabilities. values())
probabilities = {key: val/prob_sum for key, val in probabilities.items()}

print(sum(probabilities.values()))
# 0.9999999999999994
```

Alternatively, invert the number of occurrences (relative to the total count) and calculate the proportionally weighted probability of that data.

```py
total_count = sum(my_dict.values())
inverted_count = sum(total_count - val for val in my_dict.values())
probabilities = {key: (total_count-val)/inverted_count for key, val in my_dict.items()}

print(sum(probabilities.values()))
# 1.0
```

Comment: Based on the code provided, all the probabilities, irrespective of how big or small the value is in the dictionary, the prob assigned is ~0.01. This is not really correct.

Comment: Sure it's correct. The important factor is the relative probabilities of the different values. With 100 keys in `my_dict` and a relatively even distribution of values you would certainly expect many/most resultant probabilities to be 1/100 (~0.01).

Answer (score -1):

I have written a small function incorporating your suggestions and ideas. It would be helpful if you could upvote my question and answer if you think it works!

```
#Assign probs
def assign_probabilities(d):
    # compute sum of all counts
    total_count = sum(d.values())

    #compute probs for each key
    probabilities = {}
    for key, count in d.items():
        probabilities[key] = count / total_count

    key_probs = list(probabilities.items())

    #sort list by probability in asc order
    key_probs.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

    #assign decreasing prob based on rank in the sorted list
    for i, (key, _) in enumerate(key_probs):
        probabilities[key] = 1 - i * 0.01

    #crtical: normalize probs, so they add up to 1
    total_prob = sum(probabilities.values())
    for key in probabilities:
        probabilities[key] /= total_prob

    return probabilities
```

Comment: This is not a *weighted* distribution at all. Consider the input `{1: 1, 2: 100, 3:1000}`. If the result were to be weighted then the probability for 1 should be **much** greater than 3. Your solution puts 1 at only 0.67% higher chance than 3.

Comment: I need the sum of all probabilities to add up to 1. As per my question, and thus my code does make sense.